# How to retrieve data from an array from a mongodb document

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist

I have a question about how to retrieve data from a mongodb and how to store it in my Java code. I select all the documents (there are only 5) from my mongodb and then store its content in my Java application.

So my code is as follows:

```
public class MongoReader {
    private Invoice invoice;

    public void mongoReader () {
        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("my-url");

        try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri)) {
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("BiFiBEP02");

            MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection("bifi");

            FindIterable<Document> documents = mongoCollection.find();

            for (Document document : documents){
                invoice.setCustomerId(document.getInteger("customerId"));
                invoice.setDate(document.getDate("date"));
                invoice.setInvoiceId(document.getInteger("invoiceId"));
                invoice.setInvoiceLines(document.getList("invoiceLines", ArrayList<InvoiceLine>));
                invoice.setNote(document.getString("note"));
                invoice.setPersonId(document.getInteger("personId"));
            }

        }
        catch (MongoException mongoException) {
            mongoException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The document.getList() doesn't seem to be satisfied with my input.

An example of the the mongo document:

```
"customerId" : 2,
"date" : ISODate("2018-05-16T10:23:40.049Z"),
"invoiceId" : 1,
"invoiceLines" : [
    {
        "btwCode" : "hoog",
        "productId" : 1,
        "productName" : "BiFi worstjes voordeelstrip",
        "quantity" : 20,
        "totalPrice" : 30,
        "unit" : "kg"
    },
    {
                "btwCode" : "hoog",
                "productId" : 2,
                "productName" : "BiFi worstjes kip",
                "quantity" : 20,
                "totalPrice" : 30,
                "unit" : "kg"
    },
    {
                "btwCode" : "laag",
                "productId" : 3,
                "productName" : "BiFi worstjes extra scherp",
                "quantity" : 30,
                "totalPrice" : 100.22,
                "unit" : "kg"
    },
    {
                "btwCode" : "geen",
                "productId" : 1,
                "productName" : "BiFi worstjes promotiestand",
                "quantity" : -1,
                "totalPrice" : 30.32,
                "unit" : "kg"
    }
],
"note" : "This invoice is very important!",
"personId" : 2
```

So my question here is: I have to put the invoiceLines in arraylist in my Java object, but I cannot get the array items out of the mongoDb. How do I do this?

Comment: Please explain what `doesn't seem to be satisfied with my input` means.

Comment: document.getList(Object key, Class<T> clazz). I thought ArrayList<InvoiceLine> would do the trick for clazz, but its not working unfortunately. I do not know what to put there, so that I get the correct data. If I hover the error in my IDE (IntelliJ) it says "Expression expected", but what kind of expression?

Comment: I hope [this](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/08/24/retrieve-array-from-mongodb-using-java/) helps. Your explanation is a little vague.